# How to return duplicates from list in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, duplicates

I am trying to write a predicate which deletes all the unique elements of a list (and return the duplicates) like this:

```
?- delete_unique([a, b, a, a], L).
L = [a, a, a]
```

Although my code isn't working.

```
delete_unique([],[]).
delete_unique([H|T],[H|Solution]):-
   member(H,Solution),!,
   delete_unique(T,Solution).
delete_unique([H|T],[H|Solution]):-
   member(H,T),
   delete_unique(T,Solution).
delete_unique([H|T],Solution):-
   %%not(member(H,Solution)),
   %%not(member(H,T)),
   delete_unique(T,Solution).
```

Comment: `delete_unique([H|T],[H|Solution]):-
member(H,Solution),!,...` When the second argument to `delete_unque/2` query is a variable, this logical path will always be taken since Prolog will successfully unify the variable to `[H|Solution]`, and `member(H, Solution)` will also always succeed in that case since `Solution` is subsequently variable. This problem has been posted a few times here on SO, so you could just check the [SO search results for `[prolog] remove unique elements`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+remove+unique+elements).

Comment: Can you please post the output.?

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicates, if the order doesn't matter, the easiest is to use `sort/2`:

```
?- sort([a,a,b,b,c], X).
X = [a, b, c].

?- sort([c,c,a,a,b], X).
X = [a, b, c].
```

Of course, you see that the original order of the elements is lost. More importantly, this only guarantees to be correct if the list you are sorting is already ground (no free variables in it).